# Database lock on simple actions on Geopackages in QGIS3

Tags: qgis-3, geopackage

I saw similar posts, but my problem is "worst"... The geopackage locks even on very simple operations, on a single layer. I can't pinpoint specifically what triggers it: sometimes, I can make a few changes before it locks, and other times it will lock instantly.

What I'm doing right now is simply move entities in a basic point layer.

Toggling off and on the Edit button usually solves the issue... but it comes back on the next feature.I tried to place the Geopackage in various locations in case it was directory related, to no avail. I also made sure no other program were to access the Geopackage at the same time.

This renders Geopackage usage almost impossible, as it multiplies by 4-5 the necessary time on projects...

Any idea?

Comment: Could you collect some simple test case? What is needed is points from some public source like OpenStreetMap, if you do not want to share your GeoPackage, and description about what kind of edits to do for re-producing the issue.

Comment: I could share the gpkg, but honestly, it happens on every one I use. To test this, I created a new one from scratch, with a simple point geometry. As soon as I enter edit mode to move the point anywhere, the problem randomly happens.

Comment: I created a new GeoPackage with a point layer, digitized some points, and started to move the points with the vertex tool. I made a few hundred edits and saved the edits every now and then, entered and exited the edit mode. I did not face any locking problem. Unfortunately it does not help you to know that I don't have problems. I would try if installing QGIS again would resolve the problem and make a test with another computer if it happens to be hardware related.